# Custom view with textField and button not responding

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have custom view with some labels, a text field and a button. When I add it to a view in a VC, the custom view appears nicely, but I can't tap on the text field or on the button, they are not responding. Can someone tell my what is the problem with the code? Here is the simplified version:

```
import UIKit

class CustomView: UIView {
    
    let title: UILabel = {
        let title = UILabel()
        title.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24)
        title.text = "Title"
        title.numberOfLines = 0
        title.textAlignment = .center
        title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return title
    }()
    
    let textView: UITextField = {
        let textView = UITextField()
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.placeholder = "Placeholder text"
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        textView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        return textView
    }()
    
    
    let searchButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        button.setTitle("Tap me", for: UIControl.State.normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    private func setupView() {
        
        addSubview(title)
        addSubview(textView)
        addSubview(searchButton)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            title.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 100),
            title.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor),
            title.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor),
        ])
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: title.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60)
        ])
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            searchButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            searchButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            searchButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            searchButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60)
        ])
        
    }
    
    @objc func buttonAction(_ sender:UIButton!)
    {
        print("Button tapped")
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setupView()
    }
    
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let customView = CustomView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(customView)
        
        customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        customView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        customView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        customView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Basically I want to have a seperate file with the view that has all the design and I just want to drop that into the VC without doing anything special with it. Is this even a good approach? Where should I set up the button action? I mean once its tappable...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this first - at the end of `viewDidLoad()`, add this line:

```
customView.backgroundColor = .red
```

When you run the app, you'll notice there is no red box.

Now, add this line after that one:

```
customView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Run it again, and... we see **nothing**!

The problem is, you haven't given your `customView` any height.

To fix it, constrain the bottom of `searchButton` in your custom view class:

```
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
        searchButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
        searchButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
        searchButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
        searchButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
        
        // add this line!
        searchButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -20),

    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `userInteractionEnabled` to `true` on your `CustomView` instance so that it passes through taps.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(customView)
      
    customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    customView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    customView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true 
    customView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    customView.userInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

You can use a delegation pattern or a closure property to pass the button tap event back to the containing view controller.

For example,

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    var searchTappedHandler: ((CustomView)->Void)?

    @objc func buttonAction(_ sender:UIButton!)
    {
        print("Button tapped")
        self.searchTappedHandler?(self)
    }
}
```

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(customView)
      
    customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    customView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    customView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true 
    customView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    customView.userInteractionEnabled = true

    customView.searchTappedHandler = { _ in 
        print("Search button was tapped")
    }
}
```

Or, if you want to use a function rather than an inline closure

```
func handleTap(_ customView: CustomView) {
    print("tap")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(customView)
      
    customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    customView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    customView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true 
    customView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    customView.userInteractionEnabled = true

    customView.searchTappedHandler = handleTap
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! unfortunately, I still can't tap on the items, adding `customView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` didn't help. The other part is OK though, that's clear now how I should do that, thanks again.